# Convert long into numbers jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use below jquery:-

```
    exportTable.find('td#column5').css("mso-number-format","0");
```

But it is not working while if i hardcode for eg:-

```
   <td id="column5" style='mso-
  number-format:"0"';>-374857899483837484</td> it works fine.
```

I need to assign this format dynamically how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply css properties through `css()`, that should be camelCase. Try

```
exportTable.find('td#column5').css("msoNumberFormat","0");
```

Comment: This and you also have a typo in your hardcode or javascript (one is mso, the other one is ms).

Comment: Are you sure ? jQuery docs says, `jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css( "background-color" ) and .css( "backgroundColor" ). This means mixed case has a special meaning, .css( "WiDtH" ) won't do the same as .css( "width" )`

Answer (score 0):

Your style declaration is `'mso-number-format:"0"'` not `'mso-number-format:0'` so the jquery should be `.css("mso-number-format",'"0"')` not `.css("mso-number-format","0")`.

Whether to use dashes or camel case is optional, camel case is only required when passing an object to `css` instead of two arguments *and* when not wrapping the object keys in quotes.

But also it does look like part of your attempt has `ms-` instead of `mso-` so I'd take a look at that too.

Comment: Tried .css("mso-number-format",'"0"') but still not working